# Why my chrome crash when downloading ISO image file by using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

As title, my target is to monitor download status(total file size&current load file size). So, I write a simple code to help. But there exist a strange situation that is my chrome crash when download ISO OS image file(not picture file!!!). Are there any wrong of my code? BTW, when I observe console log for total size file and current load size file. I can't realize where the loaded file exactly store location.(but it indeed progress...until load 1GB then crash!) Are there any one who knows that?

```
<body>

    function TriggerProgressEvent() {
        //var progressBar = document.getElementById('p');
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var x = document.createElement("PROGRESS");
        console.log('Entering TriggerProgressEvent');

        xhr.open('GET', 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/features/upload/en_windows_server_2012_r2_essentials_x64_dvd_2707177.iso',true);
        xhr.send();

        xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
            if(event.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(event.total);
                console.log(event.loaded);
                x.setAttribute("max", event.total);
                x.setAttribute("value", event.loaded);
                document.body.appendChild(x);
            }
        };
        xhr.onloadend = function(event) {
            //console.log(event.loaded);
            x.setAttribute("value", event.loaded);
            document.body.appendChild(x);
        };
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Running out of memory? How much free RAM you got?

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=87772

Comment: To  Alexander O'Mara: It seems ran out of memory.(1025 free RAM but I download 3.9GB OS image). Should I clear the buffer dynamically? And I want the file can save as the folder that I want. Is it possible?